# ReactiveCocoa: block is never executed

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

In my app, I have a download manager. After any of tasks is finished I need to get all data for tableView again and reload it. But I can't get data inside `RACObserve` signal. Here's my code.

```
NSArray *activeTasks = [[DownloadManager instance] tasksToProcess];
for (DownloadTask *task in activeTasks) {
        [[[self
        checkTask:task]
        map:^(id value
            return [self fetchDownloadedData];
        }]
        subscribeNext:^(NSArray *models) {
            // models returns RACDynamicSignal not NSArray
            NSLog(@"%@", models); // <RACDynamicSignal: 0x11611cb50> name:
            NSLog(@"checktask next");
        } completed:^{
            // This is never being executed
            NSLog(@"checktask completed");
        }];
}

- (RACSignal *)checkTask: (DownloadTask *)task {
    return [RACObserve(task, isFinished) map:^id(id _) {
        return nil;
    }];
}

- (RACSignal *)fetchDownloadedData {
     return [[MyCoreDataModel fetchAll] flattenMap:^id(NSArray *models) {
         // This is never being executed
         return [models filter:^BOOL(MyCoreDataModel *model) {
            return model.isDownloaded;
        }];
    }];
}

- (RACSignal *)fetchAll
{
    return [[[MyCoreDataModel findAll] sortBy:@"title"] fetch];
}
```

Would be great if someone helps me getting where is my mistake is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few mistakes:

1. In `map` function you use method which returns `RACSignal` - it's not correct. You should use `flattenMap` instead.
2. **Complete** block will never be called, because `RACObserve` - hot signal, it only sends `next` event.

I wrote small example, I hope it helps you.

```
NSMutableArray<RACSignal *> *signals = [NSMutableArray array];
for (DownloadTask *task in activeTasks) {
    RACSignal *signal = [[RACObserve(task, isFinished) ignore:@NO] take:1];
    [signals addObject:signal];
}

@weakify(self);
[[[RACSignal merge:signals] flattenMap:^RACStream *(id _) {
    @strongify(self);
    return [self fetchDownloadedData];
}] subscribeNext:^(NSArray *models) {

}];
```

Here I created array of signals. Each signal - observing the `isFinished` property. Also I added `ignore:@NO] take:1];` - I think it's more right, because you only need **YES** value and after that no observe anymore (`take:1`). Then I merge these signals and each time when someone of them sends **finished** state, we fetch data.

Please, let me know if something is not understand, I try to explain more clearly.